# How to print patterns in one line in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to print 'H' in a pattern using '*':

```
def grid_h():
    result_str='';
    for row in range(5):
        for column in range(5):
            if((column == 0 or column == 4)
            or (row == 2)):
               result_str = result_str + '*'
            else:
               result_str = result_str + ' '
        result_str = result_str + '\n'
    return result_str
```

I'm trying to print HH in the same line but it always go to the new line.

I know there is an end='' at Python 3 to stay in the same line but I have tried this and still not working:
print(grid_h(), end=''), print(grid_h())

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre]. What exactly did you try, how did you call this function, what do these variables mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as @tripleee has mentioned in the comment, I think you should read the guidelines on how to ask questions.

anyway, just to give you a hint, your function returns this unformatted string: `'*   *\n*   *\n*****\n*   *\n*   *\n'`

Doesn't matter whether you have the `end=''` flag in `print()` or not, the newline is included in that string that your `grid_h()` function returns.

If you want the `H` logo thingy to be side by side, then you need to figure out how to fix where the `\n` character is placed...